# How to use vue.js transition-group with vee-validate?

Tags: css, vue.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

- vee-validate: 2.0.0
- vue: 2.4.2
- Bootstrap-sass v. 3.3.7

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Move-Transitions

What I’m trying to achieve is a transition-group animation similar to one shown in the link above - the one where when an element of an array is removed or added, the whole list moves.

This animation works with a list of input fields that are rendered with v-for.

But suddenly when I add v-validate to an input field the move animation doesn't work when removing one input field from the list - the field just disappears.

This is my code:

```
<transition-group name="interval-list" tag="div">
                    <div v-for="(interval, index) in interval" v-bind:key="interval.id" class="interval-list-item row">
                            <div class="col-sm-10 col-xs-9">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        {{index + 1}}.
                                    </span> 

                                   <input v-validate="{required: true, max: 50}" 
                                     v-bind:key="interval.id" 
                                     type="text" class="form-control" 
                                     v-bind:value="interval.name" 
                                     v-on:input="updateSingleIntervalName(index, $event)">
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <div class="error">
                                        {{errors.first('intervals'+interval.id)}}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
</transition-group>
```

Note that there's no problem with validation of the field - errors work as expected.
Somehow vee-validate interferes with v-move animation - any idea what could cause this issue?